# Getting error in TravelItineraryAddInfo response.

Tags: xml, api, sabre

I am getting the following error in the TravelItineraryAddInfo Response

> "CHECK TIME.NOT ENT BGNG WITH"
>   "ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE"

Request:

```
<TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="2.0.2">
<AgencyInfo xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10">
<Ticketing PseudoCityCode="xxxx" TicketTimeLimit="05-07T16:04" TicketType="7TAW"/>
</AgencyInfo>
<CustomerInfo xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10">
<ContactNumbers>
<ContactNumber LocationCode="Country" Phone="9xxxxxxxxx" PhoneUseType="B"/>
</ContactNumbers>
<Email Address="asdf@asdf.com"/>
<PersonName NameNumber="1" PassengerType="ADT">
<GivenName>Adult MR</GivenName>
<Surname>One</Surname>
</PersonName>
</CustomerInfo>
</TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ>
```

if any one has faced such issues please let me know the solution.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

according to Sabre's helpdesk's answers and my researches, the successful method is:

- TicketTimeLimit attribute's minute value must be '00'.
- TicketTimeLimit's date must be at least on the next day, and must precede the earliest segment date in the PNR.

so, if, for example, the current date is 2015-10-27, and the first flight in the PNR starts at 2015-11-20 13:45:00, then the earliest valid value is "10-28T00:00" (tested, works), and the latest is "11-20T13:00" (NOT tested it, but sabre helpdesk guy wrote: "The date must be the same as or preceding the earliest segment date in the Passenger Name Record (PNR).

I would advise to use a future date to avoid this.").

UPDATE!!!
i've just tested the last valid date with various values, in order "11-20T13:00", "11-20T00:00", "11-19T23:00", "11-19T00:00", "10-29T00:00"... and always got message: "INCORRECT TIME LIMIT - VERIFY  *PQ  DATE - LAST DATE 28OCT".
so, the latest valid date is (according to my latest researches - and it is TESTED!):
"10-28T23:00" (so what error message says is true).